# php/mySQL on XAMPP: password for phpMyAdmin and mysql_connect different?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am running phpMyAdmin and MySQL on XAMPP for Windows.

I am accessing the MySQL database in two ways.  First, via `localhost/phpmyadmin`, and second, via a `connection.php` file (with `mysql_connect('localhost','user','password')` which is used by other php files for a website on the server.

Both for the phpMyAdmin login and the `mysql_connect` I am using the root user. I know I should not be using root and that it is a security issue.  But the passwords differ! I have set the password for the phpMyAdmin access via `localhost/security`, but I can't figure how to change the password required for the `mysql_connect`.

I thought it would be the same but apparently it is not.  How do I change the root password through phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

if you open `localhost/phpmyadmin` you will find a tab called "User accounts". There you can define all your users that can access the mysql database, set their rights and even limit from where they can connect.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: In phpmyadmin you have to hit the home icon in the top left in order to see the user accounts tab. I used this method to change the root user's pw and then got access denied when trying to use phpmyadmin. Solution was to also update the pw in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the password directly in the database because at mysql the users and their profiles are saved in the database.

So there are several ways. At phpMyAdmin you simple go to user admin, choose root and change the password.